# Randomizing the order an agent calls a procedure?

Tags: netlogo

I have an 5 procedures I'd like an agent to perform but I need them to randomize the order in which they perform them.

For example:

1) possible ordering

```
 ask turtles [ move eat breed search spawn]
```

2) another possible ordering

```
     ask turtles [spawn eat move search breed]
```

3) another possible ordering:

```
ask turtles [search breed eat move spawn]
```

and so on. Is there there an efficient way to execute the procedures in random order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make a list of tasks, shuffle the list, then run each task in the list:

```
let procedures (list (task spawn) (task eat) (task move) (task search) (task breed))
ask turtles [foreach shuffle procedures [run ?]]
```

Comment: You're a real mensch Matt. Thanks a ton.